# R function to add multiple new columns based on values from a group of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, plyr

I am trying to figure out a clean way to add multiple new columns corresponding to multiple existing columns all at once in R. I want each new column cell to be a 0 if the corresponding cell in the corresponding column is an NA value, or a 1 if the corresponding cell has any other value (see example tables below).

I have been able to accomplish this by creating the new columns first, then with a messy which function and a loop. I was wondering if there was a clean way to do this and add in all the new columns with values at once.

Start data

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | NA |
| NA | 4 |

After function is applied

| A | B | A New | B New |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | NA | 1 | 0 |
| NA | 4 | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R,

```
df[paste0(names(df), 'new')] <- +(!is.na(df))
df

#   A  B Anew Bnew
#1  5 NA    1    0
#2 NA  4    0    1
```

`!is.na(df)` gives you logical values (`TRUE` for non-NA values and `FALSE` for `NA` values). Adding `+` at the beginning changes the logical values to integer values (`TRUE = 1`, `FALSE = 0`).

Answer (score 2):

With `tidyverse`, you can use `across` then apply a function to all columns (i.e., `everything()`), or you could specify select columns as well. Then, I use `.names` to create the two new columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), 0,1), .names = "{col} New"))
```

**Output**

```
   A  B A New B New
1  5 NA     1     0
2 NA  4     0     1
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(5L, NA), B = c(NA, 4L)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```